# How to globally add a custom Serializer to Jackson and be used by default

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

Let's say I want to serialize `Boolean` into `Number` **by default**.

I know I can do it field-by-field

```java
@JsonFormat(shape = Shape.NUMBER)
private Boolean success;
```

But can I "register" my custom Serializer so that when I return an Object from my API, the `Boolean`s in the class will be serialized into `Number` in the json response.

I have the following Serializer

```java
public class MyBooleanSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Boolean> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(
                    Boolean value, 
                    JsonGenerator gen, 
                    SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {

        gen.writeString(value ? "1" : "0");

    }
}
```

And I have the following class

```java
@Data
public class MyResponse {
    private Boolean success;
    private String message;
}
```

It will be used like this

```java
@GetMapping("/hello")
public MyResponse hello() {
    Boolean success = true;
    String message = "Hi there";
    return new MyResponse(success, message);
}
```

And when I `GET` this API, I am expecting this response

```json
{
  success: 1,
  message: "Hi there"
}
```

I am expecting some Beans to be injected. I have tried

```java
@Bean
@Primary
ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addSerializer(new MyBooleanSerializer());
    return new ObjectMapper()
            .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
            .registerModule(module);
}
```

but it does not work.

I have read [this](https://howtodoinjava.com/jackson/jackson-booleans/) tutorial and seems like it needs to create the `jsonMapper` every time I want to serialize an object. All I want is whenever I return `MyResponse` from an API, the `Boolean`s are serialized into `Number`s.

Comment: did you check my answer? It should be able to solve the problem. If that is the case please consider accepting the answer in favor of future readers

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos Sorry I only get to my workplace today so I couldn't try out the answer before that. Your answer did solve the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No need for global Serializer

,just to enforce the `@JsonFormat(shape = Shape.NUMBER)` annotation globally for boolean fields.

You can just override the global rule that applies to boolean fields as to use your custom one of `Shape.NUMBER` so that you don't have to do it in every boolean field of every class.

So instead of having for `serialization/deserialization` in each filed of each class the

```
@JsonFormat(shape = Shape.NUMBER)
private Boolean success;
```

You can do it with the following code globally:

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper registerObjectMapper(){
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();            
   mapper.configOverride(Boolean.class)
         .setFormat(JsonFormat.Value.forShape(JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER));
   mapper.configOverride(boolean.class)
         .setFormat(JsonFormat.Value.forShape(JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER));
   return mapper;
 }
```

### How to apply global Serializer in case it is necessary

But if you insist on registering a global serializer so that the format is used just for serialization and not deserialization then you can do it with:

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper registerObjectMapper(){
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("MyBooleanSerializer");
    module.addSerializer(Boolean.class, new MyBooleanSerializer());
    module.addSerializer(boolean.class, new MyBooleanSerializer());
    mapper.registerModule(module);
   
    return mapper;
}
```

And

```
public class MyBooleanSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Boolean> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(
                    Boolean value, 
                    JsonGenerator gen, 
                    SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {

        gen.writeString(value ? "1" : "0");

    }
}
```

### There is a catch

See closely in second solution the

```
module.addSerializer(Boolean.class, new MyBooleanSerializer());
module.addSerializer(boolean.class, new MyBooleanSerializer());
```

and in first solution the

```
  .configOverride(Boolean.class)
  .configOverride(boolean.class)
```

For `Jackson` the primitive `boolean` as field and the Wrapper `Boolean` class need to be registered separately in order to be able to work.

Comment: This solved my problem. However, after adding the bean, incoming request params cannot be deserialized into a POJO class with `@NonNull` members. I had to add a no-arg constructor (or `@lombok.NoArgsConstructor`) in order to work.

Comment: @Panagiotis Amigo? Any idea for this??? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75601647/how-to-globally-add-a-custom-serializer-to-format-all-instant-values-in-spring-b

Comment: @panagiotis could you pls look at similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77026240/json-deserialize-geolattegeom-point-in-spring-boot

Answer (score 1):

Can be done with a custom `StdSerializer` like

```java
class CustomBooleanSerializer extends StdSerializer<Boolean> {

    public CustomBooleanSerializer(){
        super(Boolean.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Boolean value, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        generator.writeNumber(value ? 1 : 0);
    }
}
```

And configure this via a `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer`

```java
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jsonCustomizer() {
  return builder ->
    builder.serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS) // <-- optional
           .serializers(new CustomBooleanSerializer());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the serializer, the boolean value is converted into the form of true  or false

```
public class NumericBooleanSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Boolean> {
    
    public void serialize(Boolean b, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        jsonGenerator.writeNumber(b ? 1 : 0);
    }
}
```

that will serialize booleans as 1 or 0.