# How to globally add a custom Serializer to format all Instant values in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, datetime, jackson

I am trying to format Instant fields globally in my DTOs as I can format the other date fields as shown below:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
   
    private static final String DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss";

    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jsonCustomizer() {

        return builder -> {
            builder.serializers(new LocalDateTimeSerializer(
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_TIME_FORMAT)));
        };
    }
}
```

However, I think I should follow another approach by creating anew bean as shown below:

```
@Bean
ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configOverride(Instant.class)
            .setFormat(JsonFormat.Value.forPattern(DATE_TIME_FORMAT));
    return mapper;
}
```

It changes my Instant values, but not a proper format:

```
"createdAt": {
            "nano": 0,
            "epochSecond": 1677445697
        }
```

So, how can a manage it properly in my Spring Boot app?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to globally add a custom Serializer to Jackson and be used by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75093378/how-to-globally-add-a-custom-serializer-to-jackson-and-be-used-by-default)

Comment: It does not make sense to format an `Instant` into `dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss`  format. An `Instant` hasn’t got date and hour-of-day. To derive such from an `Instant` you would need to assume a time zone or UTC offset.

Comment: @OleV.V. I use instant for `createdAt` fields in order to keep creation date for the records. I think it is a suitable datetime type for this purpose. On the other hand, cannot I display Instant values in format? Or what should I do? Could you pls explain a little bit more instead of writing something like a news title?

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos I read that page before opening the question, but could not use it for Instant. Could you post an answer by modifying it for Instant?

Comment: There are solutions for formatting instants (and yes, it’s the right type to use). In plain Java I would do like `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss").withZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Copenhagen")).format(createdAt)` to supply the time zone and get an output like `01.03.2023 12:49:40`. I don’t think I have tried it with Jackson, so sorry that I can’t help you there.

Comment: @OleV.V. No problem amigo, thanks a lot for your useful tips. I am just wondering this issue regarding to Instant. Could you clarify me? >>> As far as I know, Instant uses UTC as time zone and when saving time data, we assume that the data is saved based on UTC as time zone. Then, when we display this data, we should convert it to the client's time zone and display it? Is that true?

Comment: Up to interpretation. The `parse` and `toString` methods of `Instant` use UTC, but conceptually an `Instant` has not got any time zone. An `Instant` is a point in time, nothing more.

Comment: @OleV.V. Then, is it a bad idea to convert Instant to a formatted date-time while displaying Instant time?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252224/discussion-between-ole-v-v-and-fredrick).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has already been answered for a similar case under this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75095148/7237884).

But since OP can't find the appropriate modification to make it work for his case, here is the solution that will work here

As already described in comment this does not seem optimal to use since converting to String you will have to assume a Timezone which is not contained in Instant object.

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper registerObjectMapper(){
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("MyInstantSerializer");
    module.addSerializer(Instant.class, new MyInstantSerializer());
    mapper.registerModule(module);
   
    return mapper;
}
```

And then you also need

```
public class MyInstantSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Instant> {

    private static final String DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss";

    private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_TIME_FORMAT).withZone(ZoneId.from(ZoneOffset.UTC));

    @Override
    public void serialize(
                    Instant value, 
                    JsonGenerator gen, 
                    SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {


        gen.writeString(formatter.format(value));

    }
}
```

Comment: Should I keep the `ObjectMapper` part in my AAppConfig class and create a new class for `MyInstantSerializer` in the config package?

Comment: @fredrick yes this will be ok

Comment: Sounds good amigo, thank you so much (I will mark it answer as always I did :) In this situation, I have some doubts for the proper usage of instant. As an experienced developer, could you pls clarify me about the following points? >>>

Comment: **1.** In order to save time for createTime or updateTime, I think it is a good choice to use `Instant`, as a timestamp. Right

Comment: **2.** But I am not sure if I need to use timezone, because as far as I know, Instant uses `UTC` as time zone. Then, do I need to use time zone only displaying data by using the time zone of the client?

Comment: @fredrick, about 1 it is best practice to store in Instant since the new java.time module is the way to go about timestamps now. 2 As far as your clients are able to receive the response again in UTC they should be ok.