# Register Geolatte Jackson module in Spring Boot 3.2

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jackson, geospatial

Would like to be able to deserialize a [Geolatte Geometry](https://github.com/GeoLatte/geolatte-geom) Point in Spring Boot 3.2 by registering the [Geolatte JSON](https://github.com/GeoLatte/geolatte-geom/blob/master/json/README.md) module successfuly and use its deserializers

I can manually register the `GeolatteGeomModule` in the controller but not get Spring Boot to pick it up automatically.

**Entity**

My Entity with the point data is:

```
@Value
@Data
public class CheckDto implements Serializable {

    Long id;
    @JsonSerialize(using = GeometrySerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = GeometryDeserializer.class)
    Point<G2D> location;
    // getters setters etc
}
```

Then my `AppConfig` to auto register the custom `GeolatterGeomModule` for Jackson:

**AppConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableEntityViews("com.nz.kiwi.model")
@ComponentScan("com.nz.kiwi")
public class AppConfig {
@Bean
public ObjectMapper mapper() {
    CoordinateReferenceSystem<G2D> crs = WGS84;
    ObjectMapper gMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    gMapper.registerModule(new GeolatteGeomModule(crs));
    return gMapper;
}
```

When I try the endpoint for this class I get stack trace:

```
Mon Sep 04 18:45:46 NZST 2023
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
No converter for [class com.nz.kiwi.view.HealthCheckDto] with preset Content-Type 'application/json'
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter for [class com.nz.kiwi.view.HealthCheckDto] with preset Content-Type 'application/json'
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:319)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:245)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1740)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

It appears from the above the `GeolatteGeomModule` is not picked up.

If I modify my controller to call the `GeolatteGeomModule` manually and remove the `@JsonDeserialize(using = GeometryDeserializer.class)` from the entity so that I have:

**Entity**

```
@Value
@Data
public class CheckDto implements Serializable {

    Long id;
    //@JsonSerialize(using = GeometrySerializer.class)
    //@JsonDeserialize(using = GeometryDeserializer.class)
    Point<G2D> location;
    // getters setters etc
}
```

And my controller to:

**Controller**

```
@Autowired
private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

// register the GeoLatteGeomModule
public ObjectMapper mapper() {
    CoordinateReferenceSystem<G2D> crs = WGS84;
    ObjectMapper gMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    gMapper.registerModule(new GeolatteGeomModule(crs));
    gMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    return gMapper;
}

// Get test data with location
@GetMapping(value = "/custom5/{id}", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<?> BirdSummaryDTOCustom5(@PathVariable Long id) throws JsonProcessingException {
    HealthCheckDto hcDto = customBirdRepository.customQuery5(id);
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = mapper();
    String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(hcDto);
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .header("Custom-Header", "birdApp")
            .body(json);
}
```

I get the expected result:

```
    {
        "id": 5,
        "catchDateTime": "2023-06-05 11:18",
        "releaseDateTime": "2023-06-05 11:45",
        "location": {
            "type": "Point",
            "crs": {
                "type": "name",
                "properties": {
                    "name": "EPSG:4326"
                }
            },
        "coordinates": [
            173.5,
            -35.5
        ]
    }
}
```

How can I make spring register the module so it does this automagically?

Comment: this is a problem with the library you use. -> https://github.com/GeoLatte/geolatte-common/issues/29 There is a cycle reference so Jackson can't serialize/deserialize this DTO.

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos nice find. Its closed? Which if my attempts looks closest? I never hit a breakpoint in the geolatte module so not sure I am calling it right.

Comment: Not the self reference in Try one objectMapper() referes back to its own method name - hence self ref error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of creating your own Object Mapper it's easier to customize the one that Spring Boot creates automatically for webapps.

There are multiple ways this can be done as described here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-customize-jackson-objectmapper

In your case this should be sufficient:

```java
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jsonCustomizer() {
    CoordinateReferenceSystem<G2D> crs = WGS84;
    return builder -> builder
            .serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
            .modules(new GeolatteGeomModule(crs),
                    new JavaTimeModule());
}
```

With this customizer and the following sample controller and DTO:

```java
@RestController
class GeolatteTestController {
    @GetMapping(value = "/custom5/{id}", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<?> BirdSummaryDTOCustom5(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .header("Custom-Header", "birdApp")
                .body(new CheckDto(id, point(WGS84, g(4.33, 53.21))));
    }
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class CheckDto implements Serializable {
    Long id;

    Point<G2D> location;
    // getters setters etc
}
```

hitting `localhost:8080/custom5/123` will produce the following result:

```json
{
  "id": 123,
  "location": {
    "type": "Point",
    "crs": {
      "type": "name",
      "properties": {
        "name": "EPSG:4326"
      }
    },
    "coordinates": [
      4.33,
      53.21
    ]
  }
}
```

Tested with Spring Boot 3.2.0-M2 and `org.geolatte:geolatte-geojson:1.9.1`.

Comment: I copied your example closely - There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Type definition error: [simple type, class org.geolatte.geom.crs.AngularUnit]
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.geolatte.geom.crs.AngularUnit] at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:489)

Comment: Well, as I mentioned, the example I provided is tested and working as expected with the specified versions of libs. Apparently, you're doing something differently, so I'd suggest you to share a minimal reproducible example with your issue somewhere so that I can take a closer look. Without that I doubt it will be possible to get to the cause of the problem.

Comment: I agree it is somewhere else with in the project. Thank you for your excellent answer,

Answer (score 0):

In your example you don't use Auto-wire at all.

In your first code better change function name:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public ObjectMapper myCustomMapper() {
    CoordinateReferenceSystem<G2D> crs = WGS84;
    ObjectMapper gMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    gMapper.registerModule(new GeolatteGeomModule(crs));
    return gMapper;
}
```

Whenever you need it Autowire it like this:

```
@Autowired
ObjectMapper myCustomMapper;
```

In controller remove this:

```
// register the GeoLatteGeomModule
public ObjectMapper mapper() {
    CoordinateReferenceSystem<G2D> crs = WGS84;
    ObjectMapper gMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    gMapper.registerModule(new GeolatteGeomModule(crs));
    gMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    return gMapper;
}
```

and this:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = mapper();
```

and autowire like this

```
@Autowired
ObjectMapper myCustomMapper;
```

Comment: Thanks I tried.  Failed to complete request: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Class org.geolatte.geom.json.GeometrySerializer has no default (no arg) constructor
2023-09-05 06:24:22 - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Class org.geolatte.geom.json.GeometrySerializer has no default (no arg) constructor

Comment: The serializer/deserializer module should register and that kick in when needed on a point property automatically

Comment: You should NOT use the @JsonSerialize/@Deserialize annotations. They're not necessary. This answer is the correct way to use the Geolatte Geojson module

Comment: @KarelMaesen thanks for update on annotations. If I try the way above : with /String json = myCustomMapper.writeValueAsString(hcDto); - I am having to put the json vary in the response body (rather than the object.

Comment: Maybe Jackson2HttpMessageConverter is the better `@Bean` to register? Like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49454849/how-can-i-register-and-use-the-jackson-afterburnermodule-in-spring-boot